# Rename [norwegian-citizen] tag to [norwegian-citizens]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

A new question deserves a [norwegian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norwegian-citizens) tag, however the system won't allow me to create this tag because we already have a [norwegian-citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norwegian-citizen) tag (note singular vs. plural).  Our convention is that these tags are plural, so we should probably rename the existing tag (which as of now has exactly two questions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done. [norwegian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norwegian-citizens) is the master, [norwegian-citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norwegian-citizen) is a synonym to it.